# Swift - how to correctly use MBProgressHUD.h?

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

I have some functions and I want to show progreeeHUD during they are working

i come up with two functions showing and hiding hud

```
 func showHud() {
    let hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
```

and

```
func hideHud() {
    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
```

I tried to do like this

```
viewDidLoad

showHud()

func1()
func2()
func3()
func4()

showHud()
```

but this doesnt work, hud is not showing

also i tryed this

```
@IBAction func goToGame(sender: UIButton) {


    let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressHUD.labelText = "Loading..."

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) {

        self.JSONRequest()
        self.loadFromDb()
        self.checkForDupl()
        self.saveToDb()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            progressHUD.hide(true)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toGameSegue", sender: nil)

        }
    }
```

the problem here is that viewController, that must be shown after "toGameSegue" doesnt wait for completion of JSONRequest and following and so the app crashes because it doesnt have needed data

Answer (score 1):

**Without Block**

Try this for Visible:

```
let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
loadingNotification.labelText = "Loading"
```

To dismiss the ProgressHUD:

```
MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
```

**In your case:**

```
@IBAction func goToGame(sender: UIButton) {


    let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressHUD.labelText = "Loading..."

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)) {

        self.JSONRequest()


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        }
 }

func JSONRequest()
{
        //write it to success block
           self.loadFromDb()
            self.checkForDupl()
            self.saveToDb()
             progressHUD. hide (true)
             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toGameSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but unfortunately this doesnt work to me. I updated the post. Can u please take a look ?

Comment: it is ok to call  JSONRequest() twice ?

Comment: No. Why you call twice?

Comment: oh, sorry, i read not correctly. Do I understand correctly that after updating UI it runs completion block which is placed after JSONRequest() declaration ?

Comment: or all functions are called from inside func JSONRequest() ?

Comment: same problem - segue performs before data is loaded :(